# CASE WHEN SQL Syntax Error

Tags: sql

I am attempting to us the CASE statement for the first time and I cannot understand why I am getting a syntax error on the last WHEN and ELSE. I am trying to extract a `substring` if a value starts with a specific set of characters. My Code is below:

```
    SELECT
CASE
        WHEN LEFT ([RCode],2) = 'BB' THEN SUBSTRING([RCode],3,LEN([RCode]))
        WHEN LEFT ([RCode],4) = 'APT-' THEN SUBSTRING([RCode],5,LEN([RCode])
        WHEN LEFT ([RCode],4) = 'PS-' THEN SUBSTRING([RCode],4,LEN([RCode])
        ELSE [RCode]
END

  FROM [Xperdyte].[dbo].[tJCLines]
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the syntax error?  What database are you using?

Comment: Why are you selecting the left 4 characters and compare it to a 3 char literal string?

Comment: You're missing closing brackets on the second and third WHEN//THEN lines

Comment: That's a case _expression_. (It has a return value.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't (necessarily) fix your syntax problem, but I would recommend that you use `like` for the comparisons:

```
    SELECT (CASE WHEN RCode LIKE 'BB%' THEN SUBSTRING([RCode], 3, LEN([RCode]))
                 WHEN RCode LIKE 'APT-%' THEN SUBSTRING([RCode], 5, LEN([RCode]))
                 WHEN RCode LIKE 'PS-%' THEN SUBSTRING([RCode], 4, LEN([RCode]))
                 ELSE [RCode]
            END)
  FROM [Xperdyte].[dbo].[tJCLines];
```

Then you don't have to count characters -- and the third condition will match.

Answer (score 0):

Missed off two right parenthesis.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEFT([RCode],2) = 'BB' 
            THEN SUBSTRING([RCode],3,LEN([RCode]))
            WHEN LEFT([RCode],4) = 'APT-' 
            THEN SUBSTRING([RCode],5,LEN([RCode]))
            WHEN LEFT([RCode],4) = 'PS-' 
            THEN SUBSTRING([RCode],4,LEN([RCode]))
            ELSE [RCode]
       END
FROM [Xperdyte].[dbo].[tJCLines]
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. I knew it was something simple.